# Cannot select from table, but I can insert and create?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, mysqli

I have this extremely weird issue with mysql. I can insert into, and create tables. However I cannot select anything and it does not display any error when I try, it just echos my line "Error: "

```
getDiff("validTable");

function getDiff($regNr) {
    global $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    //todo
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $regNr ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result === TRUE) {
        echo "done";
    } else {
        $error = $result->error;
        echo "Error: " . $error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

But when I insert to the DB using this

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $regNr ( `id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `mail` INT NOT NULL , `price` INT NOT NULL , `views` INT NOT NULL , `the_date` DATE NOT NULL , `time` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) )";
runQuery($query);

function runQuery($todo) {
   global $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;
   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   //todo
   $sql = $todo;

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       echo "done";
   } else {
       echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
   }
   $conn->close();
}
```

It works just fine and dandy. WHAT HAVE I DONE WRONG?! This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows only "Error" because your `query` succeeds and returns a `mysql object` which is not equal to `True` and therefore it does not echo `done`

See (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Change your code with the code below to make it work:

```
   if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
       echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
   } else {
       echo "done";
   }
```

Basically turning the if around such that it checks for FALSE or not FALSE.

Most probably you also want to store the result in a variable like:

```
   if ($result = $conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
```

And later on use `$row = $result->fetch_array()` or `$row = $result_fetch_assoc()` to get the data.

Comment: THANK YOU! Also many more thanks for fetch_array()! Been working too long to see the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

**[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)**

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
> EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
> other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

As per this condition

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

You get `mysqli_result` from your query and this is not equal to TRUE and you always goes into error condition

To fetch data from query use **[fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)**

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0]);
```

To get error form query we use  `$conn->error` not `$result->error` it need your connection variable not your result variable

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php